Parse JSON using TrinoSQL
How I can parse the below JSON using Trino.
[
  {
    "district_name":"District name",
    "attributes":[
        {"survey_date":"2024-08-29","commodity_name":"ABC","avg_spot_price":123},
        {"survey_date":"2024-08-29","commodity_name":"DEF","avg_spot_price":456}
      ]
  }
]

I'm using below SQL but it is raising error.
SELECT
  district_name, attributes
FROM 
    UNNEST(CAST(JSON_EXTRACT(districts_data
                            ,'$'
                    ) as ARRAY(ROW(district_name VARCHAR, attributes ARRAY(ROW(survey_date VARCHAR, commodity_name VARCHAR, avg_spot_price DOUBLE)))
                )
          )
    ) as x(district_name, attributes)


"but it is raising error." - what error?
